# sql trigger update and insert

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.3

I have a problem with sql in language 'plpgsql'.

The question is to add a new column clean_phone in customers table first. Then use trigger on insert and update to populate clean_phone to random_string() function. Here is what I did.

create a new column

```
alter table customers
add clean_phone varchar(15);
```

trigger

```
create or replace function clean_function() 
returns trigger as  
$$
begin
new.clean_phone = random_string();
return new;
end;
$$ 
language 'plpgsql';

drop trigger clean_phone on customers;
create trigger clean_phone
before update or insert 
on customers 
for each row
execute procedure clean_function();
```

And final, show the table

```
select name,clean_phone from customers;
```

The problem I have is after I run all code and show the result, the clean_phone column still not showing anything. So, how could I fix this?

Comment: Are you inserting or updating anything in the table?  The trigger is only called under those circumstances.

Comment: I try to insert/update on anything but it shows error that clean_phone not exist

Comment: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(15)
SQL state: 22001
Context: PL/pgSQL function clean_function() line 3 at assignment

Answer (score 0):

Please check first that random_string() function exist or not by using :-

select random_string();

If you get result then please let me know because it's working fine at my end.

Answer (score 0):

**Use This Code :-**

> Create or replace function random_string(length integer) 
>   returns text as
>
> $$
>
> declare chars text[] := '{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z}';
>
> result text := '';
>
> i integer := 0;
>
> begin
>
> if length < 0 then
>
> raise exception 'Given length cannot be less than 0';
>
> end if;
>       for i in 1..length loop
>
> result := result || chars[1+random()*(array_length(chars, 1)-1)];
>
> end loop;
>
> return result;
>
> end;
>
> $$ language plpgsql;

```
create or replace function clean_function() 
returns trigger as  
$$
    begin
        new.clean_phone = random_string(15);
        return new;
    end;
$$ 
language 'plpgsql';
```